# How to append the data into the file that exists data

Tags: c++, c

I have a file that has struction as:

```
A.txt 1 
B.txt 2
C.txt 3
```

Now, I want to open the file and append the new data such that new data is created by the second column adding by 2, and same row with data get from that coulmn by C/C++
For example

```
A.txt 1 3
```

where 3=1+2, 1 is data at the first row, 2 is weighted factor
And finally, my expected result is

```
A.txt 1 3
B.txt 2 4
C.txt 3 5
```

I can read and get the data such as:

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen('input.txt','a+');//Is it correct for append and read mode
 if(!fp)
   return -1;
 int icheck=-1;
 int thirdNum=0;
 int num=0;
 icheck= fscanf(fp, "%s %d", filename,&num);
 thirdNum=num+2;
 //How to append it to file as same row with the A.txt or B.txt or C.txt
```

Thank you so much

Comment: C or C++? The answer might vary depending.

Comment: i think it is better if I use C. Because I use visual studio 2010 to implement it and standard reading file is C

Comment: You can use `a+` for reading+appending... http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Comment: @user3121023: We don't have other option?

Comment: Yes, to add data in middle of files, you will have to rewrite entire file.

Comment: That mean I will make the new temp file and write in to it. Because we cannot delete the file when we are reading it. Could you suggest to me how to rewrite the file without make new temp file

Comment: @user3121023: If I seek to the beginning, It cannot read the data in the second row. Is it problem?

Comment: @user3121023: Only 4 byte that type is int.

Comment: "how to rewrite the file without make new temp file"  Yes it is possible to do it this way, but it is better to create a temp file and upon successful completion, close the original file, then delete the original and rename the temp file to the original file name.  This has 1 huge advantage: should an error occur _somewhere_, you always have at least one good copy of the data.

Comment: @Chux: I implemented by your way but the result of rename function is -1, although I closed both file-temp and original file. For temp file, I use 'w+' mode to write

Comment: The original and temp file can not have that same name at the same time.  Are you attempting that?

Comment: Right. I must delete original file. And then rename it. THank you

Comment: 1) Insure all temp files have a unique name - there are function calls for that.  2) After reading original and writing temp, close all files.  3) Rename the original to a 2nd temp name. 4) Rename 1st temp to original. 5) lastly, delete original, which now goes by the 2nd temp name.

Comment: The rational for all these steps is to address how things look should a failure occur in any one step.  Maybe due to IO error or lack of permissions to do a certain step like rename or delete.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can do it this way:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {

    std::string filename = "file.txt", line;
    std::ifstream ifs( filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if (!ifs) // check if the file exists and can be read
        throw std::runtime_error( "cannot open the file");

    std::stringstream buffer; // buffer to store the lines

    while ( getline( ifs, line)) {

        int previous_value;
        std::istringstream iss(line.substr(line.find_last_not_of(" ")));
        iss >> previous_value;
        buffer << line << "\t" << (previous_value + 2) << "\n"; // add integer
    }

    std::ofstream ofs( filename.c_str(), std::ios::out); // ofstream buffer
    ofs << buffer.rdbuf(); // write to the file

    return 0;
}
```

This can be made more memory efficient if one avoids the copy of all the file content into temporary buffer.

Comment: @user3730173 you have thrown C++ tag away while I was writing this, is this then still relevant? Then please retag your question.